# Open set such that $\text{int}(\partial A) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Is there any example of an open set $A$ such that  $\text{int}(\partial A) \neq \emptyset$ ?
I'm having problems trying imagine such a set, is it false then?

Comment: I believe there is... try thinking rationally about.

Comment: @freeRmodule Clever wordplay

Comment: You're probably imagining a set whose boundary is very thin, like a disk in the plane. Can you think of a set whose boundary is "fatter", perhaps even dense in the parent space, or even ALL of the parent space?

Comment: Why do you insist an a "non-empty" set $A$? Is there an easy example if you drop that requirement?

Comment: I know you all are going to be highly displeased because I forgot one of my main hypothesis, (mathematical sin), I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 4):

There indeed cannot be an open set with that property: If $A$ is open, $A\cap\partial A=\emptyset$. But by definition of the border, in any neighbourhood of any point of $\partial A$ there's an element of $A$, which therefore isn't in $\partial A$. So there's no point in $\partial A$ that has a neighbourhood in $\partial A$, and thus the interior of $\partial A$ is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and $T$ be a topology of $X$ defined as follows: $$T=\{\varnothing ,X\}$$
Now choose $A=\{1\}$. Then the boundary of $A$ will be the whole of $X$.

Comment: I noticed that OP changed the question and is looking for an **open** set $A$ such that blablablah. You might want to review your answer.

Comment: I think user254665 and celtschk both got a good answer !

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an open subset of the space  $X. $ Then $A\cap \partial A=\phi:$ Because $X$ \ $A$ is closed, so $\partial A=\bar A \cap \overline {X \backslash A} =\bar A \cap (X$ \ $A) =\bar A$ \ $A  .$

If $ U\subset \partial A,$ where $U$ is open, then the open set $U$ is disjoint from the open set $A,$ so $U\cap \bar A = \phi.$ So $U=U\cap \partial A\subset U\cap \bar A=\phi.$

So int$(\partial A)=\phi.$